# Place bootstrap cards in horizantal order

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, crud

I have a simple page with a navbar + one main-body div + one footer.
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is the navbar and footer remain in that position no matter what, while only the main white space show these bootsrap cards, but in horizontal position max-4 per row. What I managed so far is:

```
 <div="wrap> 
      <navbar boostrap>
     </navbar>
     <form>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   <footer>
   </footer>
```

And applying this css for the wrap div and the footer:

**WRAP**:

```
.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -12vh;
  padding-bottom: 12vh;
}
```

**Footer**:

```
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  height: 12vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #393e46;
}
```

What I did after is adding a class to my form that encapsualtes the bootsrap card and in css doing this:

```
.form-events {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Is there a better practise or my solution works??

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do as follows if you are using **Bootstrap**.
Keep the navbar and footer as it is. Only thing you will need to work on is the main whitespace part.

1. First create a `<div></div>` which has a class of **container** as such `<div class="container"></div>`
2. Then you can put another `<div></div<` element with a class of **row**, so that your cards will be placed in same row horizontally `<div class="row"></div>`
3. Next you can use the `col` classes that Bootstrap offers, to create a div element for each of your cards `<div class="col"></div>`. It is basically used for defining how many elements you will need in a single row and it makes your content responsive.
   Be sure to check the **documentation** here if you need more details: [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/)
4. Finally you can put your cards. Just remember to wrap a single card inside each `<div class="col"></div>`
5. Below you can find the code example of how I did it. Run the snippet in **full page** to see the cards horizontally; **otherwise**, it will show then stacked on top of each other because of screen size

From my experience, I would suggest using **container** class for a `div` to put your elements in, especially card elements.

[JSFiddle Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4qzn79va/1/)

**EDIT** : If you have a problem where your cards stack on top of each other while resized, wrap all of them up in `"card deck"` class inside a `<div>` element

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
<div class="row ">

<div class="card-deck">

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, yes this seemes to work but in your case at some point on my screen the contents of each card overlapped each other before stacking vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the     `position:fixed`     line to your ".footer" CSS class like so.

```
 .footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 12vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #393e46;
   }
```

By doing this it will stay positioned at the bottom of the page even if a user scrolls down the page.